# Object Sender and EventArgs

Tags: c#, events, parameters

Consider this function signature:

```
Private Void TextBox1_TextChange(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
```

As far as my knowledge goes I understand it as below.

1. Private is a modifier
2. Void is the return type
3. `TextBox1_TextChange` is an event name.

Maybe I am wrong in the above case as I just started practicing in C#, Visual Studio 2005.

What is the definition/meaning of `(Object Sender, EventArgs e)` and how does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TextChange` is (probably) the name of the relevant event, though the event isn't shown in your code snippet so I can't be sure.

`TextBox1_TextChange` is the name of a method that is probably set up to handle an event.

`Object Sender` is a parameter called `Sender` that contains a reference to the control/object that raised the event.

`EventArgs e` is a parameter called `e` that contains the event data, see the [EventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx) MSDN page for more information.

See this page, [Passing Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z%28VS.71%29.aspx), for more information about how parameters work.

And this page, [Events Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28VS.71%29.aspx), would probably be helpful as well.

Comment: Sir, So the above i mean "Private Void TextBox1_TextChange (Object Sender, EventArgs e)" is a method or an Event?

Comment: @mahesh: It's a method that's handling an event, so it can be called an `Event Handler`. An event will look something like `public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;` and then the `Event Handler` is hooked up to the `Event` using the `+=` syntax as described in the tutorial linked to in my answer.

Comment: Sir, Here i am accepted ur valuable and important answer for me. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Object Sender: which object is invoked the current event.in your case TextBox1 is sender.
EventArgs e :e is the object for EventArgs, when TextChange is invoked object e contain arguments.